# What is the best way to run a continuous loop in php that only runs if it's not already running?

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

LAMP stack on Ubuntu 18.04:

I have a php loop that I want to continuously run. It is my understanding that Apache will spawn a thread per script that is executing and give one core to it and that's effectively what I'd like to do: Have a php script that constantly loops, processing things as it needs to.

I've seen methods of running a cron every minute that create a file and then delete it when it is done but what happens when the script takes 61 seconds to execute and then it's just sitting around not doing anything for 59 seconds. Or if the script crashes and doesn't delete the file.

Before doing this the wrong way, I wanted to find out what the *right* way is.

Comment: Describe your real problem which you try to solve with some infinite loops.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run a long running polling script in order to do work as it arrives.  There are many ways to do this, and none of them involve Apache.  Your best choice is to use a job server to queue your jobs.  I like beanstalkd, but just about any job queue will be sufficient.  All of your long running jobs should be started on the command line as a service, preferably using the pcntl or pthreads extension.  If you want an example project, I threw this together for beanstalkd: https://github.com/kwhat/legume

Answer (score -1):

The "check if file exists" is an "ok" approach... You can replace it by a row in some database using the same logic.

You can avoid the timeout problem by checking if the file date (or database record date) is older than 1 minute. If it is, then the last process failed to delete the file and you can do it and start the process again.

Answer (score -1):

To me it sounds like you want to reinvent event-driven model using apache and mod_php, which are not created for event-driven models.
If you want to stick with php, I would suggest just running php_cli script (not related to Apache) in the console (maybe as systemd service). When it starts it should verify that it is not started already. Or you can use a .lock or .pid file.

Comment: I would like to know more about this approach. I've only used php with apache so I'm completely ignorant to the other options available to me. Is there a tutorial or primer you can point me to?

Comment: There is a php cli interpreter that operates in much the same way as mod_php and fcgi php.  You can run PHP from the command line using `php -f script.php` and do just about everything you can do with mod_php plus a few extra things.  More reading on using PHP as a Posix service:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php This is not a PHP concept; this is how service signaling works on *nix. I already gave you a sample project.